# Why do I have this assumption that "string" is not a native c++ data type

Tags: c++

I write simple programs in C++ using Visual Studio C++.

when I use keyword `string` for my datatype, it is not colored as datatype, though it works (well,  should be `#included`).

I check microsoft website for Data Types, and I see int all the way down to double etc. But I see no data type named "string". Why?

Why I always see char and/or unsigned char is used as datatype. Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: String is not a native c++ data type, you are correct. It is defined in the stl, which you'd be crazy to not use.

Comment: `std::string` is *not* a native type. Likely some header you're including is back-including `<string>`, which is perfectly acceptable, but not to be relied on unless specifically stated within the library standard. It *is* provided  by the standard library. it is not a native *type*. Rather it is library provision (an unless I'm mistaken, said-provision is required for library standard compliance). You should be able to use it without worry unless you're on the most non-compliant embedded system imaginable.

Comment: then for holding a large amount of text, for instance the content of a contact form, what data type should be used?

Comment: @MostafaTalebi - Why not use `std::string`?

Comment: `std:string`  is what you should use.   Just because it is not native doesn't mean you should not use it.   No-one writes code without `#including` many many libraries.   In fact, a critical skill of programmers these days is their ability to find and select the appropriate libraries

Comment: This shows no research. Your intuition is correct, googling would have confirmed this.

Comment: Most languages have two big parts.  The language itself and the libraries that go with the language.  You will probably spend more time learning the libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Built-in" types like `int`, `char` and `unsigned char` are called fundamental types in the C++ standard (§3.9.1). `std::string` is not a fundamental type, it's a part of the standard library. Standard header files like `<iostream>` may include `<string>` but you shouldn't rely on this behavior and should explicitly include header files when you need them.

Comment: well this lighted the way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`string` is not a C++ keyword, as `int` or `char`.

If you want to make it look like a keyword, you could do it via [**usertype.dat**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy61y8b8%28v=VS.71%29.aspx).

BTW, Visual Studio 2013 shows `string` as any other class (light blue on my system).